# How to use regular expressions to extract multilingual content

Tags: php, regex

I should extract multilingual content from a text structures in this way:

> some text [it] italian text [/it] [en] english text [/en] bla bla bla
>
> other text [it] other italian [/it] [en] other english text [/en] bla bla bla

I would extract all the text not enclose beetwen multilingual square brackets and the text enclosed beetwen current language square brackets.

For example if the current language is "en" I would extract the following text:

> some text english text bla bla bla
>
> other text other english text bla bla bla

How could I use regular expressions to correctly extract the text?

Comment: Why have you jumped to the conclusion that the solution _must_ involve regular expressions?

Comment: You've asked quite a few questions in the past which seem to have good, popular answers; you haven't accepted them. Please do so now.

Comment: That's a horrible thing to use regular expressions for.

Comment: Because I've thought that to use regular expressions could be a good solution. Have you some suggestions for using an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like

```
 $result = preg_replace_callback("~\[ (\w+) \] (.*?) \[ /\\1 \]~sx", 
       function($m) { return $m[1] == "en" ? $m[2] : ""; },
       $text);
```

Comment: Replacing `== "en"` with `== "it"` when you want Italian I presume?

Comment: Thank you very much, it's an excellent and very smart solution!

Differently from your example I had to use create_function() to create the anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that those tags are correctly balanced and will never be nested (which looks like a reasonable assumption), you could do this:

```
$result = preg_replace('%\[it\].*?\[/it\]\s*|\[/?en\]\s*%s', '', $subject);
```

This specifically looks for  and removes `[it]`-enclosed text (and the `[en]` tags themselves).

**Explanation:**

```
\[it\]     # Match [it]
.*?        # and everything that follows until 
\[/it\]    # the nearest [/it]
\s*        # plus any trailing whitespace
|          # or
\[/?en\]   # Match [en] or [/en]
\s*        # plus any trailing whitespace
```

If you want to remove any text between tags except text between `[en]` tags, then it gets a little more complicated (still assuming no nested tags):

```
$result = preg_replace('%\[(?!/?en\b)([^\]]+)\].*?\[/\1\]\s*|\[/?en\]\s*%s', '', $subject);
```

**Explanation:**

```
\[         # Match [
(?!/?en\b) # Assert that this is not an [en] tag
([^\]]+)   # Match and capture the tag name (anything until the next ])
\]         # Match ]
.*?        # and everything that follows until 
\[/\1\]    # the nearest corresponding closing tag
\s*        # plus any trailing whitespace
|          # or
\[/?en\]   # Match [en] or [/en]
\s*        # plus any trailing whitespace
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a group and a back-reference on the tag?

Comment: Ah, I see - we need to find any tag that is not `en`, not just those that are `it`, right? Good point - will edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think better do not use preg_replace for this

```
$languages = array(
      'en'=>array(
          'label' => 'english label'
      ),
      'it'=>array(
          'label' => 'italian label'
      )
    );

    $language = "it";
    $someTextForItalian = "bla bla bla bla %s bla bla bla.";    
    $someTextForItalian = 
         sprintf(
           $someTextForItalian,
           $languages[$language]['label']
         );
```